# Find indexes of multiple minimum in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, minimum

I want to find the indexes of the minimum of an array.

E.g.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,1,7,8,9,1];

var min = Math.min.apply( Math, array )
var key = array.indexOf(min);
```

The problem is that Math.min.apply return only the first index

min = 1 and key = 0

What I want to do is to return

```
min = 1 and key = [0,4,8];
```

Is it possible to do it with Math.min.apply?

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,1,7,8,9,1];

function findMinimumIndexes(array) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, array);
    var indexes = [];

    array.forEach(function(item, idx, arr) {
        if (item === min) {
            indexes.push(idx);
        }
    });

    return indexes;
}

console.log(findMinimumIndexes(array));
```

The function declares the variable `indexes` and assigns to it an empty array which then it fills up using a `forEach` call with elements' indexes whose value matches `min`.

Notice that this only works for primitive values since it uses `===` to check for equivalence.
To make it work on arrays or objects that are 'deeply equal' to the one you are looking for, you would need a more rigorous implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,1,7,8,9,1];
var min = Math.min.apply( Math, array )

var arrayWithIndex = array.map(function(element, index) {
    return element + "-" + index;
});

var minValues = arrayWithIndex.filter(function(element) {
    return Number(element.split('-')[0]) === min;
});

var keys = minValues.map(function(element) {
    return Number(element.split('-')[1]);
});
```

My algorithm is mapping the original array to include a new array that contains both the number and index. I'm then filtering that array for elements, where the number is equal to min, and then mapping again to find the index.

You can also chain these methods

```
return array.map(function(element, index) {
    return element + "-" + index;
})
.filter(function(element) {
    return Number(element.split('-')[0]) === min;
}).
.filter(function(element) {
    return Number(element.split('-')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Array.prototype.reduce` should do the work.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 1];

function getMinKeys(array) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, array);
    return array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a === min && r.push(i);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getMinKeys(array), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Why `a === min && r.push(i);`? Does it even bring a performance improvement?

Comment: compared to what? it is just shorter to write `a === min && r.push(i);` than `if (a === min) r.push(i); `.